# render dynamic template in react something similar to $compile in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I have the following code in angular and I wonder how easy it can be "converted" to react. Here is what I am doing in angular

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.directive('myPlugin', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(scope, element) {

     // Data loaded dynamically from db
     var plugin_templ = '<h1>Hello {{who}}</h1>';
     var plugin_script = 'scope.who = "world"';

     eval(plugin_script);

     var compiled = $compile(plugin_templ)(scope);
     element.append(compiled);
    }
  }
})
```

Basically I load template and code from the database and compile it on the fly. Is there a similar way to do this in react ?

p.s. I am well aware how "dangerous" it can be and that I shouldn't use eval etc. However, it is done so.

Comment: Very interesting question, actually there's a nice thread about it and people are trying to work this out. https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact/issues/80 check this link out. JSX Transformer is prolly what you looking for. Problem with react rendering constantly and injecting script or markup like this may affect performance

Comment: I almost posted a working example, but I couldnt get passed template literal string. Couldn't get it to work, cuz it wasn't parsing correctly. If you dont care about plugin_script part, everything else should be ok